# Не полная обработка директивы v-if

Tags: html, vue.js

Какое то странное поведение v-if в цикле v-for он почему то отображает только первое попавшиеся истинное условие в v-if, а остальное или не обрабатывает или пропускает, как то странно, почему не проверяются все условия

> К примеру com.Evaluation == 'true' в первом блоке а условие v-else-if="com.Evaluation != 'false' во втором блоке не выполняется

```
<div class="media" v-for="com in media">
    <div>
        <template name="ON" v-if="com.Evaluation == 'true'">
            <label v-bind:id="'labelUp' + com.ID" v-bind:for="'buttonUp' + com.ID">{{com.Like}}</label>
        </template>
        <template name="OFF" v-else-if="com.Evaluation != 'true'">
            <label v-bind:id="'labelUp' + com.ID" v-bind:for="'buttonUp' + com.ID">{{com.Like}}</label>
        </template>
        <template name="NULL" v-else-if="com.Evaluation == ''">
            <label v-bind:id="'labelUp' + com.ID" v-bind:for="'buttonUp' + com.ID">{{com.Like}}</label>
        </template>
    </div>

    <div>
        <template name="ON1" v-if="com.Evaluation == 'false'">
            <label v-bind:id="'labelDown' + com.ID" v-bind:for="'buttonDown' + com.ID">{{com.Unlike}}</label>
        </template>
        <template name="OFF1" v-else-if="com.Evaluation != 'false'">
            <label v-bind:id="'labelDown' + com.ID" v-bind:for="'buttonDown' + com.ID">{{com.Unlike}}</label>
        </template>
        <template name="NULL1" v-else-if="com.Evaluation == ''">
            <label v-bind:id="'labelDown' + com.ID" v-bind:for="'buttonDown' + com.ID">{{com.Unlike}}</label>
        </template>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: что значит `первое попавшееся`?

Comment: К примеру com.Evaluation == 'true' а уже следующие v-else-if="com.Evaluation != 'false' шлет лесом

Comment: При использовании `v-if`, `v-else-if`, `v-else`, на одном уровне, будет выбран только один блок. Если необходимо независимо проверять условия, то необходимо заменить `v-else-if` на `v-if`

Comment: Вы же видите что здесь два разных блока <div> и во втором блоке v-if

Comment: приведите пример, который воспроизводит ошибку/не ожидаемое поведение

Comment: К примеру в  com.Evaluation значение 'true' первого блока а значит условие v-else-if="com.Evaluation != 'false' во втором блоке тоже должно обрабатываться, но этого не происходит

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно объединить в один блок

```
<div class="media" v-for="com in media">
        <template name="ON" v-if="com.Evaluation == 'true'">
            <label v-bind:id="'labelUp' + com.ID" v-bind:for="'buttonUp' + com.ID">{{com.Like}}</label>
        </template>
        <template name="OFF" v-if="com.Evaluation != 'true'">
            <label v-bind:id="'labelUp' + com.ID" v-bind:for="'buttonUp' + com.ID">{{com.Like}}</label>
        </template>
        <template name="NULL" v-if="com.Evaluation == ''">
            <label v-bind:id="'labelUp' + com.ID" v-bind:for="'buttonUp' + com.ID">{{com.Like}}</label>
        </template>
        <template name="ON1" v-if="com.Evaluation == 'false'">
            <label v-bind:id="'labelDown' + com.ID" v-bind:for="'buttonDown' + com.ID">{{com.Unlike}}</label>
        </template>
        <template name="OFF1" v-if="com.Evaluation != 'false'">
            <label v-bind:id="'labelDown' + com.ID" v-bind:for="'buttonDown' + com.ID">{{com.Unlike}}</label>
        </template>
        <template name="NULL1" v-if="com.Evaluation == ''">
            <label v-bind:id="'labelDown' + com.ID" v-bind:for="'buttonDown' + com.ID">{{com.Unlike}}</label>
        </template>
</div>
```